# Why are exceptions in partial postback (UpdatePanel) not logged to eventlog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

In a standard postback, if an exception occurs, the error is logged to the event log under the source "ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0".  Lots of good details here.

If an exception occurs during a partial postback function via an UpdatePanel call, why is the exception not logged to the event log, and is there something I need to enable to cause that functionality to work?

I can verify that in both cases the OnError function of the page does fire, but only in a postback does the error get logged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the exceptions aren't logged to the event log

Here are some not-so-nice work-arounds I've  found so far:

### Rethrow in `AsyncPostBackError`

Catch the exception in the `ScriptManager`'s `AsyncPostBackError` event. Wrap it and throw it.

#### Disadvantages

1. The client JavaScript code loses the original exception message.
2. The exception is wrapped unnecessarily, which may make debugging a tiny bit more tedious.

### Disable `EnablePartialRendering`

Disable `EnablePartialRendering` on the `ScriptManager`.

#### Advantages

1. Errors handled in a manner that is consistent with non-async postbacks.

#### Disadvantages

1. Seems to kind of defeat the purpose of using `UpdatePanel`s.
2. You lose access to some client-side classes such as `Sys.WebForms`.